# Running/Online version of Numpy Unique?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a NumPy array and I'd like to know how many unique elements are in the first N entries in the array, at each possible N = 1, 2, ..., len(array). For instance, suppose my array is [3, 3, 2, 1, 2]. I'd like to count the number of unique elements up to (and including) index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. For this array, the answer would be [1, 1, 2, 3, 3].

How can I do this?

Is there a faster way to do this that doesn't involve the following list comprehension?

```
num_unique_elements_by_end_index = [len(np.unique(arr[:idx+1])) for idx in range(len(arr))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A python solution using `list` and `set`:

```
In [1]: alist = [3, 3, 2, 1, 2]
In [2]: aset=set()
In [3]: for i in alist:
   ...:     aset.add(i)
   ...:     print(len(aset), aset)
   ...: 
1 {3}
1 {3}
2 {2, 3}
3 {1, 2, 3}
3 {1, 2, 3}
```

np.unique is a relatively complex function, that sorts the argument, and from that detects duplicates.

Comment: Ah, so if unique sorts, there's no way to use it in an "online" manner.

Comment: I think you mean 'inline', or actually cumulative.  Anyways it does not use hashing like `set` so you can't build on previous calls.  `numpy` isn't that great for tasks like this that are inherently serial.

Comment: I wasn't sure what the correct word was. Online and running both seemed off. If inline or cumulative is better, feel free to edit the post's title.